# Why does render_template doesn't work in ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

Why does render_template doesn't work i'm trying to make a login form that returns the home page after successful login

here is my ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.logBtn').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      data : {
        email : $('#emailInput').val(),
        password: $('#passInput').val()
      },
      type : 'POST',
      url : '/process'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      if (data.error) {
        $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
        $('#successAlert').hide();
      }
      else {
        $('#successAlert').text(data.name).show();
        $('#errorAlert').hide();
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

and here is the python

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():

    email = request.form['email']
    password = request.form['password']

    if password and email:

        user = Db().login(email, password)

        if user:
            session['user'] = user
            session.modified = True
            return render_template("home.html", user='user')

    return jsonify({'error' : 'Incorrect username and password.'})
```

Comment: what doesn't work ? what is the error you get ? you are sure that it's not your login that fails ? What happens when you validate the form ?

Comment: what do you mean by validate the form